# Mac OS X find process memory regions addresses

Tags: c, macos, process

Is there a way to read the `process memory regions addresses` under Mac OS X like in Linux accessing `/proc/$pid/maps`? Couldn't find anything. I want to be able in C to dump a specific process memory region.

Comment: Check [vmmap](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/vmmap.1.html) command line tool

Comment: Thanks, found some example here: https://github.com/elliotcm/Kitchen-Sink/blob/master/mac_dump.c

Comment: To complete your example, a vmmap clone source code here : http://www.newosxbook.com/src.jl?tree=listings&file=12-1-vmmap.c